# WP Touch Thumbnail Images Dont Show in Category Posts

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I am using WPTouch to create a mobile version of my website BetterHousekeeper.com.

Everything looks great on the homepage but when you go into category posts (using your mobile) like http://betterhousekeeper.com/category/category-gardening/ the thumbnails disappear on the left side. How do I make the thumbnails appear for these posts?

Seems like WPTouch disabled this option in category posts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this question has been solved. It is in the wptouch - customizer - blog - post thumbnails - select ALL